# How to align the right side of an inline child menu with its parent menu item

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down menu with a child menu. Both are displayed inline one below the other.

The problem is that the main menu is floated to the right so when the child menu is displayed, the child menu starts to go off the right side of the screen. Especially when the child menu has a lot of items.

I want the right side of the child menu to be in line with the right of the parent menu item. In my case the left side of the child menu is aligned with the left side of its parent item.

Is this possible?

Here is some of the code from firebug (not sure if its helpful):

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="left">
 <li class="divider"></li>
 <li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-33">
 <li class="divider"></li>
 <li id="menu-item-43" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-43">
 <li class="divider"></li>
 <li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-44">
 <li class="divider"></li>
 <li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-36 has-dropdown">
 <li class="divider"></li>
 <li id="menu-item-48" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-48 has-dropdown">
  <a href="#1">PR News</a>
  <ul class="dropdown" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
   <li class="title back js-generated">
   <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-52">
    <a href="#1">SA Courts</a>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-50">
   <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-51">
   <li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-49">
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your code it will be easier to debug.
I think in your case you can use position: absolute for child menu

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.menu-main-menu li{
    position:relative;
}
.dropdown{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

You might have to put a `min-height` rule on `.menu-main-menu` so that the child-menu-item doesn't overlap the main content of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The following prototype might help you.  Use absolute positioning on the sub-menu block to position it to the right edge of the parent `li` element.

I found it a bit easier to use inline-blocks for the secondary menu items instead of float.  If you want to use floats, you need to specify a with for `.sub-nav`, otherwise the items just wrap onto multiple lines unless the top level label is very long and the secondary labels are very short.

```css
.main-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main-nav li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  height: auto;
}
.sub-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}
.sub-nav li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li>First Tag</li>
  <li>Second Tag</li>
  <li>Third Tag</li>
  <li>Fourth Tag
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li>First Tag</li>
      <li>Second Tag</li>
      <li>Third Tag</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```